# How to perform either update query if data is present else insert the data in Mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, insert, insert-update

I wanted to know **if data is present then there must be mysql update query else insert data into mysql table.**

What I have done is, I am fetching data from .csv file into mysql using **fgetcsv()** function.
Then reading each row from csv & putting those four values in four variables & then firing update query. 
SO how can I check that if one of the data is not present still update query is working(0 rows successfully updated) so I want to identify that data & **insert** that into table else if data present my **update** query will work.

I want to either update or insert data into product_entity_price  table.
My script-:

```
    if(($handle = fopen("/data/sample/items_0420.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) 
    {          
         while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 8000, ",")) !== FALSE)      
         {
        $num = count($data);
        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) 
        {             
            $temp = $data;             
            $string = implode(";", $temp);           
        }
            $pieces = explode(";", $string);               
            $col1 = $pieces[0];
            $col2 = $pieces[1];         
            $col3 = $pieces[2];               
            $col4 = $pieces[3]; 

    $query_insert = "INSERT INTO import_prices (customer_id, sku, price, website) ".             
    "VALUES($col1,'$col2',$col3,'$col4') ".             
    "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE customer_id=$col1, price=$col3,website='$col4' "; 
        $result = mysql_query($query_insert);

             $query_update = "UPDATE  product_entity_price pep 
             JOIN   catalog_product cp   ON    cp.entity_id = pep.entity_id    
             AND    cp.sku LIKE '$col2'   AND   website_id = $col4 
             JOIN   customer_group cg   ON    cg.customer_group_id = pep.customer_group_id   AND   cg.customer_group_code =  $col1 
SET cpetp.value = ".$col3.";";
             mysql_query($query_update);
          }
    }
```

Comment: `INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` should do that already. Any errors?

Comment: Do you have a unique key in your `import_prices` table?

Comment: HI CodeCaster , INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE working fine...but I want to either update or insert on another table product_entity_price...& we use ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE on some constraint like unique key or primary key...but in product_entity_price  there is no unique key...

Comment: HI Travesty3 , previously there is unique key in import_prices i.e sku. but now multiple skus are available so remove that constraint...so now no unique key in import_prices.

Comment: If you don't have any unique key in `import_prices`, how will MySQL know when to change from an `INSERT` to an `UPDATE`? What signifies a `DUPLICATE`? See if my answer below helps for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check mysql command replace :

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is the MySQL UPSERT, otherwise known as [INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html).

Comment: It's still the right answer.  An examination of the keys would be valuable.

Answer (score 1):

If you dont care if a row gets deleted if duplicate and inserted again then you can use [REPLACE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html)

```
REPLACE into table (col1, col2) values(val1, val2)
```

Comment: Be careful with this if you have a lot of rows to insert/update. http://code.openark.org/blog/mysql/replace-into-think-twice

Answer (score 1):

I've always found it to be most **reliable** to use two queries:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT 1 FROM import_prices WHERE ...");
list($exists) = mysql_fetch_row($result);

if ($exists)
    $result = mysql_query("UPDATE import_prices ...");
else
    $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO import_prices ...");
```

The downside to this approach is that you will always make two queries instead of one. But this approach works for tables that don't have a primary key, like a relational table.

You could also try just doing the update query and then checking `mysql_affected_rows` and inserting if it is 0, but **be warned**: if you do the update and all of the old values are the same as the new values, `mysql_affected_rows` will still return 0.